# How to default a custom-styled dropdown to browser default style dropdown

Tags: html, css

I have a custom-styled CSS class applied to a select element. It is a requirement that this class remains and is applied to the form elements on the web page. However, there are other areas of the web page which I want to place dropdown menus that default to the browsers own way of rendering dropdown menus, but I can't. The custom-styled select area applies to ALL select boxes and I'm pulling my hair out trying to solve this. Below is the code and attached is a screen grab of the rendered webpage with the code exposed to show how this is rendered whereby the class "select-area" is added when i have not expressed it to be included in the HTML code.

HTML:

```
<div>
 <label><strong class="tool-question">Select a table</strong>
  <select name="2" class="tool-input-select" id="2">
   <option value="Select">Select</option>
   <option value="Option One" selected>Option One</option>
   <option value="Option Two" selected>Option Two</option>
  </select>
 </label>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.tool-input-select {
    margin: 3px 0 6px 0 !important;
    color: #101010 !important;
    border: 1px solid #abadb3 !important;
    padding: 5px !important;
    font-size: 1.200em !important;
}
```

Please see the attached link for the rendered screen grab of the HTML:
[screen grab here](http://postimg.org/image/i2ipnpxph/)

My thanks in advance!

Nick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me that you're using a 3rd party javascript library that is automatically converting all select boxes into the custom styled look that you're getting on page load. My suggestion would be to remove each javascript library one by one to find the culprit (by looking at the style on the rendered `<select>`, i'd say it's JCF).

It's really got nothing to do with your html or css styles. You can tell this because the select box has a `jcf-hidden` style on it (so it's hidden), and your 'inspect element' is showing you a `<span>` instead of the actual `<select>`

Comment: Rudeovski, you are brilliant! It was indeed Javascript that played out in the rendering. I'll see if I can correct it so it only renders on specific IDs/classes. Thanks a lot! Nick